# Php and apache max_clients

Tags: php, apache2

I am really new to php, I have recently developed a reliability simple web interface to manage personal profiles for our robotics team.

Today was opening day, there is a few less than 40 members on the team and there were less than 25 at the meeting today.

When it was my turn to talk, I had everyone go to the website, register. All seemed well and everyone got registered. Then problems began to occur mostly logical errors in my code nothing that was any bigg deal. Then people couldn't submit anything or click on any links. The server just locked up.

What do i need to do to figure out what happened. I got the following from my web host:
"
I looked at the error log and it was complaining that max_clients had been reached.
Sure enough, apache had 150 processes running.
I can guarantee that traffic wasn't high enough to account for that, so I'd guess someone must have a glitch in a script that ties up an apache process.
Eventually they all get taken up when connections are broken. "

So what kind of investigation do I need to do to track down the problem.
Is this error like a memory leak except for processes?

Is there any known problems with php that could cause this?

thanks,
Blake

Comment: It may help if you post your php script (at least the parts dealing with your connection to the database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being that I had a while loop that was infinite.

I realize now how there is no way that anyone could begin to diagnose that problem from what was described here.

I hope my future questions are better.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to read my question.